# Make an object follow a shape in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have a simple sphere and a curvy road. When the ball starts to move with a certain amount of speed, on the edge of the curves, it is gaining momentum and starting to rise -as it should be according to physic rules- What I want to do is move the sphere along the way smoothly, without rising. No matter how much speed it gets, I don't want my sphere to rise, just follow that curvy road. I am not sure how to do it. I don't want to make bezier curve or a spline all along the road. I am confused about which method should I follow.[image]

Comment: I would try to add a rigidbody and collider to the sphere and add colliders to the curve. Use the rigidbody to add a constant base force. The engine should take care of the speed changes based on physics.

Comment: I already added rigibody and collider to the sphere and mesh collider to the road. It moves as it should be however I want to manipulate the physics and don't want my ball to rise when it gains momentum.

Comment: You can increase the mass of the game object